# linq2sql renders unnecessary ORDER BY

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a bit complex linq2sql query, it doesn't contain any 'order by' statements, but somehow linq2sql thinks it is necessery and inserts it. Unfortunately this 'order by' statement hurts performance and I don't know how to remove it...

Here's the linq2sql expressions (I don't think that they might help, but anyway...)

```
var lockedBy = Guid.NewGuid();
var locks = LinqDataContext.Instance.LockBranches(3, lockedBy, DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3)); // Stored procedure...

var x = LinqDataContext.Instance.Branches
.Where(branch => branch.LockedBy == lockedBy)
.Select
(
    branch => new
    {
        Branch = branch,
        Leaves = branch.Leaves
        .Select
        (
            leaf => new
            {
                Leaf = leaf,
                Estimate = leaf.Representation.Estimates
                .GroupBy(estimate=>estimate.SegmentID)
                .Sum
                (
                    estimatesBySegment => estimatesBySegment.Average
                    (
                        estimate => estimate.EstimateRequests.Average
                        (
                            estimateRequest => estimateRequest.EstimateSubmit.Value
                        )
                    )
                )
            }
        )
    }
);
```

It renders to the following sql

```
SELECT [t0].[ID], [t0].[IndexID], [t0].[IndexNo], [t0].[Sealed], [t0].[LockedBy], [t0].[UnlockOn], [t1].[ID] AS [ID2], [t1].[BranchID], [t1].[RepresentationID], [t1].[Xml], (
    SELECT SUM([t7].[value])
    FROM (
        SELECT AVG([t6].[value]) AS [value]
        FROM (
            SELECT (
                SELECT AVG([t5].[Value])
                FROM [dbo].[EstimateRequests] AS [t4]
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[EstimateSubmits] AS [t5] ON [t5].[EstimateRequestID] = [t4].[ID]
                WHERE [t4].[EstimateID] = [t3].[ID]
                ) AS [value], [t2].[ID], [t3].[RepresentationID], [t3].[SegmentID]
            FROM [dbo].[Representations] AS [t2], [dbo].[Estimates] AS [t3]
            ) AS [t6]
        WHERE ([t6].[ID] = [t1].[RepresentationID]) AND ([t6].[RepresentationID] = [t6].[ID])
        GROUP BY [t6].[SegmentID]
        ) AS [t7]
    ) AS [Estimate], (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [dbo].[Leaves] AS [t8]
    WHERE [t8].[BranchID] = [t0].[ID]
    ) AS [value]
FROM [dbo].[Branches] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Leaves] AS [t1] ON [t1].[BranchID] = [t0].[ID]
WHERE [t0].[LockedBy] = @p0
ORDER BY [t0].[ID], [t1].[ID]  <-- Here's the unnecessary ORDER BY
```

Comment: How do you know the order by is hurting performance?

Comment: LINQ2SQL has the awkward habit of generating LEFT OUTER JOINs where INNER joins would suffice. The only way out of this is to write the joins manually and not rely on the generated associations. It may be a bug or something... I'd suggest trying the same approach with this superfluous "order by" - just write out the joins and see if there's any difference.

Comment: Jeff, you're right I don't know, I only know that this 'order by' is redundant, and I don't want it to be there...

Comment: Stefan but if I will write out joins manually I will loose linq2sql wrappers and will have to do the wrapping manually, or there is a way to inject "tuned" sql into linq2sql query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `order by` is needed to be able to distinguish the child collection `Leaves`. (Every time you have a child collection there is an `order by`)

Comment: Ok, the first order by is needed, but still don't see, why do we need the second order by...